# In PCA, how are maximising variance and minimising reconstruction error equivalent?

Tags: optimization, principal-component-analysis

I understand that, given a normalised data matrix $X$, the PCA algorithm can be formulated as maximisation problem where objective function is:

$$ \max_{{\omega}} \omega'X'X\omega  \quad\quad \text{ such that } \quad\quad \omega'\omega = 1.$$

Or, alternatively, as a minimisation problem with objective function:

$$ \min_{\omega} ||X - X\omega\omega'||^2  \quad\quad \text{ such that } \quad\quad \omega'\omega = 1.$$

How are these two equivalent?

Comment: Is $\omega$ a matrix? If so, what does the equation $\omega’ \omega = 1$ mean? Does it mean $\omega^T \omega = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: Let $X$ be an $m \times n$ data matrix, then $\omega$ would be an $n$ dimensional vector. The vectors $\omega$ that solve these optimisation problems are the eigenvectors of $X'X$. What I would like to know is how these two formulations are equivalent.